# 2D Graphics in Window Form are not painting anything

Tags: c#, graphics

I'm trying to add 2D graphics to Windows Form Picture box.
This is my code:

```
private System.Drawing.Graphics g;

private System.Drawing.Pen pen1 = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Red);
private System.Drawing.Pen pen2 = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Aqua);

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    g.DrawEllipse(pen1,348.5f, 348.5f, 3, 3);
    g.DrawEllipse(pen2, 269.5f, 348.5f, 1, 1);
}
```

When I compile it, It runs normally but it won't display any graphics. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Did you use a debugger? Did you see anything interesting there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `pictureBox1_Paint` event for that. Also, I think you've reversed your x,y position with elipse width and height. You'll hardly see 1x1 or 3x3 sized elipse. So, try to go with this:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var pen1 = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Red);
    var pen2 = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Aqua);
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen1, 3, 3, 348.5f, 348.5f);
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen2, 1, 1, 269.5f, 348.5f);
}
```

**Result:**

[image: WinForms drawing]

Comment: To add on this. It's because the graphics instance is only temporary and is "overwritten" later on.